# bash export not included in kubectl command

Tags: bash, kubectl

i am trying to use **export** for kubectl command re-use as:

```
export do="--dry-run=client -o yaml"
```

When i echo it seems to work, and i can see the full string:

```
echo $do
```

However, when i attempt to run it fails

```
kubectl run testdo --image=nginx $do
```

**error: Invalid dry-run value (client -o yaml). Must be "none", "server", or "client".**

It is not escaping the string for some weird reason.. The following shortened, single command works fine, but i want to include a few parts to the command..

```
export do="--dry-run=client"
```

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, which version of bash are you using ? `echo $BASH_VERSION`

Comment: You are using Zsh, not Bash.

Comment: How did u fix it